Rejecting promise with error: FormatException: SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON
I have the following error in the console when uploading my flutter web application to firebase hosting, this only happens with the HTML supplied by "flutter build web", placing another HTML in index.html works, but placing the index.html that integrates "flutter build web" gives me the title error. The HTML file is
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <!--
    If you are serving your web app in a path other than the root, change the
    href value below to reflect the base path you are serving from.

    The path provided below has to start and end with a slash "/" in order for
    it to work correctly.

    For more details:
    * https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base

    This is a placeholder for base href that will be replaced by the value of
    the `--base-href` argument provided to `flutter build`.
  -->
  <base href="/">

  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta content="IE=Edge" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
  <meta name="description" content="A new Flutter project.">

  <!-- iOS meta tags & icons -->
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="solUapp">

  <!-- Favicon 
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png"/>-->

  <title>solUapp</title>
  <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">
</head>
<body>
  <script src="flutter_bootstrap.js" async></script>

</body>
</html>


I have tried to remake the project from scratch, I have done all the steps that Firebase and Flutter tell me from the documentation, the error persists. Also, on local servers it runs normally, including servers outside of flutter like python.
